# Angular fails to assign http returned result to the variable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to make an app using ionic2 + angular2, I have a trouble of getting account verification result (0:failed 1:success) from server api.

Here is the ResultCode class

```
export class ResultCode{
  result: number;
}
```

And here is the service code

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService{
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  constructor(private http:Http){ }

  authenticate(url:string,email:string, password:string): Promise<ResultCode>{
    return this.http
      .get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json() as ResultCode)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.result || { };
  }
  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

Here is the LoginPage code

```
export class LoginPage {
  resultCode:ResultCode;

  private loginForm : FormGroup;
  constructor(
   public navCtrl: NavController,
   private loginService:LoginService,
   private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     email: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.email]],
     password: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(6)]]
    });

  }
  login(){
   let email = this.loginForm.get('email').value;
   let password = this.loginForm.get('password').value;
   let url = `https://www.xxxx.com/api.pl?fn=login&email=${email}&password=${password}`;
   this.authenticate(url,email,password);
   console.log("result == " + this.resultCode.result);

  }
  authenticate(url,email,password){
    this.loginService.authenticate(url,email,password)
    .then(result=> this.resultCode = result);
  }

}
```

And I get result == undefined from console.

I can get the result

> result == 0 
>   from console, if i print it inside the .then()

```
  authenticate(url,email,password){
    this.loginService.authenticate(url,email,password)
    .then(result=> console.log("result == " + result.result));
  }
```

I am wondering if the console.log is executed before authenticate() function is done?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: try console log inside then block return this.http
      .get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json() as ResultCode)
      .catch(this.handleError);

Comment: That's right. When you call `this.authenticate(url,email,password);`, service request is in progress, and immediately you are calling `console.log("result == " + this.resultCode.result);`, which prints `undefined` as result has not yet arrived. Result arrives only under `.then`. But I couldn't understand what issue you are facing here.

Comment: i am trying to assign returned result to variable resultCode, so i can check if authentication is success or fail.

Comment: `this.authenticate(url,email,password);` is ajax call, it's asynchronous execution. In this case, `console.log("result == " + this.resultCode.result);` will execute before `this.resultCode = result` , so `this.resultCode.result` will be undefined.

Comment: thank you, Thien.  is there any way i can execute the console.log() after ajax call is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a closer look at our code here:

```js
login() {
   //...
   this.authenticate(url,email,password);
   console.log("result == " + this.resultCode.result);
   //...
}
```

The reason the console prints `result == undefined` is because inside login() you are making an asynchronous call with `authenticate()`. *While* this is running, the execution of the rest of the program continues down to `console.log()`. Because console.log() executes much faster than making a network request with authenticate(), it prints undefined, although later the value inside `this.resultCode` is actually 0.

In order to handle the response later in your program you have to wait until it arrives. So anything you want to do *after* the network request has completed needs to be coded inside the `.then()` part of your `authenticate()` function like this:

```js
authenticate (url,email,password){
    this.loginService.authenticate(url,email,password)
        .then((result) => {
           // NOW WE ARE ALWAYS SURE THE RESPONSE HAS ARRIVED
           this.resultCode = result
        });
}
```

Now, since you have the synchronous function login() calling the asynchronous authenticate(), you may want to do some things but *only after* login() and whatever it calls has completed.

The best way to do this is by using Promises. This is how I would change your code to support that:

```js
login(){
   let email = this.loginForm.get('email').value;
   let password = this.loginForm.get('password').value;
   let url = `https://www.xxxx.com/api.pl?fn=login&email=${email}&password=${password}`;

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // notice we now return a Promise here too
       this.authenticate(url,email,password)
           .then(result){
                this.resultCode = result;
                resolve (result);
           }
    };
}

authenticate(url,email,password){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // notice we now return a Promise
        this.loginService.authenticate(url,email,password)
            .then((result) => { resolve(result)); } // notice the change here, resolving the value outwards to the caller
    };
}
```

Now in anywhere else in your LoginPage code where you want to run code that you are sure is executed after login has taken place completely you can just do:

```js
login().then(){
    // NOW WE ARE SURE LOGIN HAS COMPLETED
}
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote it yet, but I will do it  when i can.